# foxpro deleted() in query

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am trying to debug an old foxpro app and I am seeing the following a query -

```
select db.column1, ..., DELETED() as columnname from ....
```

My question is as follows - what does the DELETED() in the sql statement mean?  is the a foxpro function, or is it most likely a custom function that appears in the code somewere?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DELETED() is a foxpro command that returns a logical value that indicates if the row has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Tom Brothers said, FoxPro has a SET DELETED [ON/OFF] environment setting that controls whether or not FoxPro commands process records that are marked for deletion.  This setting is scoped to the data session.

```
* Create a table with 3 records, delete the 2nd record.
CREATE TABLE "DeleteTest.DBF" (pk I)
INSERT INTO "DeleteTest" (pk) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO "DeleteTest" (pk) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO "DeleteTest" (pk) VALUES (3)
DELETE FROM "DeleteTest" WHERE (pk = 2)

* Allow VFP to access deleted records, the result will be 3 records.
SET DELETED OFF
SELECT pk, DELETED() AS delete_flag FROM "DeleteTest"

* Prevent VFP from accessing deleted records, the result will be 2 records.
SET DELETED ON
SELECT pk, DELETED() AS delete_flag FROM "DeleteTest"
```